# Sending mail in Rest Client (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, email

I am developing web service for my android app and I am having a hard time on my email function to work well.
I follow this tutorial [HERE](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/).

and in my controller I have this :

```
function forgotPassword_get(){
        $this->load->model('model');
        
        $this->response->format = 'json';
        
        $email = $this->get('email');
    
    $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
    $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';

    // gmail specific settings here
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'my email here';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password here';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';

    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    
        $this->email->from('mailfrom', 'sample name');
        $this->email->to('mailto'); 

        $this->email->subject('sample email');
        $this->email->message('sample message for email.'); 

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        
    }
```

the result is

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: sendmail
    User-Agent: CodeIgniter
    Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2013 15:45:57 +0800
    From: "sample name" 
    X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
    X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
    Message-ID: <526f67b5f16b8@mobilemo.com>
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

sample message for email.
```

it says the email is successfully sent, but I think mails not reaching my inbox.

could anyone help me, I think I'm missed something.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this one:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'emailhere@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password Here';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

i just altered your config items. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable SMTP access in Gmail, if i remember correctly you have to click on some checkbox in Gmail like "Allow 3rd party to use this account for sending mail". Also this is not good practice because Gmail will constantly warn you that someone tries to access your account.

Comment: no, and I'm doing it now, but I tried to use default settings removing the "gmail specific settings" and use some disposable email still not working.

Comment: I figure out that no need to do that.. its simply correct manipulation of config items would do.